# Upload uploading dark photo

Tags: php

I have a system for registering products, where the part of including photos is like this:

[image]

The code that on the part of the photos is like this:

```
$visualizar = '<table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Tamanho  <a href="'.$this->caminhoAbsoluto().'/modal-tamanhos/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTamanhos" style="color: #FFF"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                              <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Quantidade</td>
                              <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">EAN</td>
                            </tr>';
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_tamanho_grades WHERE IdGrades = '".$grades."';");
        ///$c = 0;
        while($isfast = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $sqlTamanhos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_tamanhos WHERE IdTamanhos = '".$isfast["IdTamanhos"]."';");
            $isfastTamanhos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlTamanhos);
            $visualizar .= '<tr>
                              <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-style:Arial">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="GradesEscolhidas[]" value="'.$grades.'">
                                 <input type="text" name="TamanhosEscolhidos[]" style="border: 0px; width: 50px; text-align: center" readonly value="'.$isfastTamanhos["Tamanhos"].'">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                   <input type="number" name="QtdEscolhidos[]" class="form-control" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" value="0">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                   <input type="text" name="EANEscolhidos[]" class="form-control" maxlength="17" style="width: 100%">
                              </td>
                            </tr>';
       }
        $visualizar .= '<tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-left">
                                <label for="fotos" class="upload">Selecionar fotos <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                <input type="hidden" name="GradesFotos[]" value="'.$grades.'">
                                <input id="fotos" type="file" name="Fotos[]['.$grades.']" multiple>
                            </td>
                       </tr>';
        //$c++;
     $visualiza[] = $visualizar;
     echo json_encode($visualiza);
```

When the user clicks sign up, it is directed to the method below:

```
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Cadastrar"){
   $fotos = $_FILES["Fotos"];
   $fotosTemp = $_FILES["Fotos"]["tmp_name"];
   $dados = array_filter($_POST);
   echo $metodos->cadastrarProdutos($dados,$fotos,$fotosTemp);  
}
```

And the method cadastrarProdutos():

```
public function cadastrarProdutos(array $dados,$fotos,$fotosTemp)
{
  ...
$gradesEscolhidas = $dados["GradesEscolhidas"];
for($f = 0; $f < count($fotos['name']); $f++)
            {
              foreach($fotos['name'][$f] as $key => $value){
                $fotosProd = $value;
                 $tempProd = $fotos['tmp_name'][$f];
                 $extensoesProd = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg','JPG');
                 $validarProd = pathinfo($fotosProd, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                 list($nomeFotoProd, $extensaoFotoProd) = explode($validarProd, $fotosProd);
                 $data = date("Y-m-d H:i");
                 $nomeFotoProd = md5($nomeFotoProd).".".$validarProd;
                 if($fotosProd == $fotoPrincipal[0])
                 {
                     $nomeFotoPrinc = $nomeFotoProd;
                 }
                 if(!in_array(strtolower($validarProd), $extensoesProd))
                 {
                     $_SESSION["ErroFoto"] = "Extensões permitidas: png e jpg";
                     $_SESSION["Erro"] = time() + 2;
                 }
                   else
                 {
                     move_uploaded_file($tempProd, '../../site/produtos/'.$nomeFotoProd);
                     $diretorioNormal = "../../site/produtos/";
                     $fotoDir = $diretorioNormal.$nomeFotoProd;
                     list($largura, $altura) = getimagesize($fotoDir);
                     if($validarProd == 'jpg' || $validarProd == 'jpeg' || $validarProd == 'JPG')
                     {
                         $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($fotoDir);
                         $x = 502;
                         $y = 529;
                         $origem_x = imagesx($imagem);
                         $origem_y = imagesy($imagem);
                         if($origem_x > $origem_y)
                         {
                             $final_x = $x;
                             $final_y = floor($x * $origem_y / $origem_x);
                             $f_x = 0;
                             $f_y = round(($y / 2) - ($final_y / 2));
                         }
                          else
                         {
                         $final_x = floor($y * $origem_x / $origem_y);
                         $final_y = $y;
                         $f_x = round(($x / 2) - ($final_x / 2));
                         $f_y = 0;
                         }
                         $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
                         imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y, $largura, $altura);
                         imagejpeg($miniatura,$fotoDir,9);
                     }
                     if($validarProd == 'png')
                     {
                         $imagem = imagecreatefrompng($fotoDir);
                         $x = 502;
                         $y = 529;
                         $origem_x = imagesx($imagem);
                         $origem_y = imagesy($imagem);
                         if($origem_x > $origem_y)
                         {
                             $final_x = $x;
                             $final_y = floor($x * $origem_y / $origem_x);
                             $f_x = 0;
                             $f_y = round(($y / 2) - ($final_y / 2));
                         }
                          else
                         {
                             $final_x = floor($y * $origem_x / $origem_y);
                             $final_y = $y;
                             $f_x = round(($x / 2) - ($final_x / 2));
                             $f_y = 0;
                         }
                         $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
                         imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y, $largura, $altura);
                         imagepng($miniatura,$fotoDir,9);
                     }
                           $query = "INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES(?,?,?);";
                           $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->conexao,$query);
                           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$idProduto,$key,$value);
                           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                      if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0)
                     {
                        $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 5;
                     }
                 }
             }
          } 
}
```

Registration usually occurs, but the photos are as follows. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: `imagejpeg()` quality range is 0-100. Many optimizations could be made in your PHP code. What is the value of `$largura` and `$altura` ? Did you try to dump them ? Is `$fotoDir` uploaded correctly ?

Comment: Hello, Syscall. The values of $largura and $altura are fixed. It worked correctly before I changed this line: `<input id="photos" type="file" name="Photos[]['.$grades.']" multiple>`, because I need to associate the photos with the Grades field. When I use : `<input id="photos" type="file" name="Photos[]" multiple>` it works normally.

Comment: I'm sorry about my English. I'm using Bing Translator.

Comment: `name="Fotos['.$grades.'][]"` should be better.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: I got it right. I changed this line: $tempProd = $fotos['tmp_name'][$f]; for $tempProd = $fotos['tmp_name'][$f][$key];